# Is there a URL scheme available for the Measure app?

Tags: ios

I would like to launch the new *Measure app* (on iOS 12) from within my app, is that possible? Does the app have an available URL scheme to use for this? Or some other way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It looks you can't open this app.

In the [Documentation Archive](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html) you can see the different system apps you can open, measure not being included.

The [new doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1648685-open) has nothing about this.

You should make your own measurement module embed inside your app, it's pretty trivial with AR Kit now