# Open Measure App (iOS) in your React Native App using a button [Expo]

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I am trying to open the [Measure iPhone App](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/measure/id1383426740) inside my react native app. I have tried to use linking but as mentioned [in this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52381126/is-there-a-url-scheme-available-for-the-measure-app), Measure does not support URL scheme or Deep Linking. Is there any other way to open the Measure App inside or be redirected to Measure App from my App in react native?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Linking, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button
          title="Open Measure App"
          onPress={this._handleOpenWithLinking}
          style={styles.button}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

  _handleOpenWithLinking = () => {
    // Should open the Measure App
    // This does not work as mentioned - Linking.openURL("measure://")
  };
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
  button: {
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
});
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Thanks!

Comment: sorry but not really